# Primitive Elements for  $S_n$ Galois Extensions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, primitive-elements

This is an offshoot of my other question two days ago.
[How to apply  Hilbert's Irreducibilty theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117820/how-to-apply-hilberts-irreducibilty-theorem)

But it is of independent interest.

Solutions of  Inverse Galois Problem for a finite group $G$
give us polynomials whose splitting field has Galois group $G$.
I would like to know if there is a way of getting the
minimal polynomial (degree equal to order of $G$) 
for a primitive element of that splitting field.

If this is too cumbersome at least
 is there a reasonable description of  a primitive element?

For example in the case of $S_n$ can we get a recursive description something 
like this? give two algebraic numbers $\alpha,\beta$
one of them of degree $(n-1)!$  such that $\alpha+\beta$ is of degree $n!$ and generates
an $S_n$-Galois extension? (as $S_n$ is generated by an $n$-cycle and an involution,
the number of degree $(n-1)!$ above could possibly be fixed by that $n$-cycle).

Known baby example:
Considering that cube roots of one and two together generate
a Galois extension with $S_3$ as Galois group 
it is straightforward to see $\omega +\sqrt[3]{2}$ as
primitive element and write down its minimal polynomial.
(It turns out to be $x^6 + 3x^5 + 6x^4 - 13x^3 - 24x^2 + 33x + 121$, quite a mouthful).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. 

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu: the opening paragraph was missed out during editing and I have restored it now.

Comment: Suppose the grround field $F$ has at $n$ distinct elements
$c_1,\ldots,c_n$ that don't sum to zero.  (For example,
in characteristic zero let $c_i=i$ for each $i$.)
Write the extension as the Galois closure of a degree-n extension
$F(x_1)$.  Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be the conjugates of $x_1$.  Then
$X := \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i$ is a primitive element, because
the conjugates of $X$ are obtained by permuting the $c_i$,
and no nontrivial permutation fixes $X$.


Comment: Moreover, one there is an explicit formula for the minimal polynomial of this element, since one can compute addition and multiplication in the ring $Q[x_1,...,x_n]$ using the obvious relations, and thus find the linear relation between $1,X,X^2,...,X^{n!}$, using polynomials.

Comment: Thanks to Elkies, and Swain. Your answers are clear and explicit and readily usable to construct.  I have now my work cut out getting that polynomial of degree 24 giving $S_4$ as Galois extension.


Comment: Resultants will suffice for S4.